# UIScrollView not scrolling off screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling, contentsize

I have an app in which a `UIScrollView` of the dimensions 1056x96 on top of a screen which is 480x320 (it is in landscape.) It contains 9 UIBUttons. It definitely is able to scroll, as when I set 'bounces horizontally' to true I can clearly see it bouncing back as soon as I attempt to scroll. It simply will not scroll beyond the bounds of the screen, and I have set its `contentSize` to 1056x960. Does anybody have a helpful suggestion as to why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `contentSize` property must be larger than the size of the `UIScrollView` its self. Once I made the size of that larger, it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure your viewForZoomingInScrollView is set to the subview rather than the scroll view itself. For example:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
return self.menuView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 'userInteractionEnabled' flag set to true?. Is the scrollView embedded into another view?. If so... please, check the 'userInteractionEnabled' flag as well.

Besides that, please, check if the flag 'scrollEnabled' is enabled both in your nib and in your code.